# Iterate multiple nested vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, c++98

Imagine there is a vector of an class A having some specific attributes. Amongst others, it has an vector of type B. Furthermore, B has, amongst others, a member variable of type vector. What is the best way to iterate all given Cs?

The naive way would be to use nested loops. To change attribute foo of an object of type C to bar something like

```
for (i=0; i<as.size(); i++)
  for (j=0; j<as[i].bs.size(); j++)
    for (k=0; k< as[i].bs[j].cs.size(); k++)
      as[i].bs[j].cs[k].foo = bar
```

If I have to iterate over all objects of class C very often this way; maybe having a more complex body; the code gets rather confusing. Besides the additional identation, these nested for loop constructs repeats through the code.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Can I declare some kind of iterator doing this for me? I am forced to use C++98.

Comment: A function encapsulating the loop that takes a functor as argument

Answer (score 1):

- You may do a function:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename F>
  void my_for_each(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>& v, F f)
  {
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i != as.size(); i++)
          for (std::size_t j = 0; j != as[i].bs.size(); j++)
              for (std::size_t k = 0; k != as[i].bs[j].cs.size(); k++)
                  f(as[i].bs[j].cs[k].foo);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  That requires a functor to use it:

  ```
  struct bar_assigner
  {
      bar_assigner(int bar) : bar(bar) {}

      operator () (int& e) const { e = bar; }

      int bar;
  }
  ```

  And use it like

  ```
  my_for_each(as, bar_assigner(bar));
  ```
- An other alternative is to flatten your array (if each inner vectors have same size):

  ```
  class Matrix3
  {
      public:
          typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iterator;

          Matrix3(std::size_t a_size, std::size_t b_size, std::::size_t c_size) :
          a_size(a_size), b_size(b_size), c_size(c_size), v(a_size * b_size * c_size){}

          int& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k)
          { return b_size * c_size * i + c_size * j + k; }

          iterator begin() { return v.begin(); }
          iterator end() { return v.end(); }

          // ...

      private:
          std::size_t a_size;
          std::size_t b_size;
          std::size_t c_size;
          std::vector<int> v;
  };
  ```

  And usage:

  ```
  for (Matrix3::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
      *it = bar;
  }
  ```
- And third alternative is to create your own iterator:

  ```
  class Iterator3D
  {
  public:
      Iterator3D& operator ++() {/*..*/}
      int& operator *() {/*..*/}
      int* operator ->() { return &this->operator *(); }
      operator ==(const Iterator3D& rhs) const {/*..*/}

  private:
      std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>& v;
      std::size_t index_a;
      std::size_t index_b;
      std::size_t index_c;
  };
  ```

  And usage:

  ```
  for (Iterator3D it = my_begin(as); it != as_end(as); ++it) {
      *it = bar;
  }
  ```